# iOS - Dropbox: Upload file error

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, dropbox

I am working on a iOS app which uploads files to Dropbox.
First the app links user to Dropbox if he is not linked yet. Then the file is uploaded using the following DBRestClient.h method:

`uploadFile:(NSString *)filename toPath:(NSString *)path withParentRev:(NSString *)parentRev fromPath:(NSString *)sourcePath;`

All this stuff worked fine (in iOS 5 and iOS 6) but suddenly it stopped working and then when I try to upload a file I get the following error:

**Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1021 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1021.)" UserInfo=0xac51810 {destinationPath=(my destination path), sourcePath=(my source path)}**

What can I do?

Comment: You say it worked fine in iOS5 and iOS6. Are you writing that code on iOS7, or is it now failing on iOS5 and/or iOS6?

Comment: It's failing now in iOS5 and iOS6

Comment: [*NSURLErrorDomain error -1021*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003793-CH3g-SW40)